# Sequelize join query with condition

Tags: join, sequelize.js

I am using the following syntax to select some records:

```js
models.account.findAll({
  attributes: ['password'],
  include: [{
    model: models.user,
    as : 'user'
  }],
  where: {
    'password': password,
    'user.email': email
  }
}).then(function(res){
  console.log(res);
});
```

It's generating the following query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   `accounts` AS `account` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` AS `user` 
        ON `account`.`user_id` = `user`.`id` 
WHERE  `account`.`password` = 'PASSWORD' 
    AND `account`.`user.email` = 'xyz@gmail.com';
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So it's giving me an error: `Unknown column 'account.user.email' in 'where clause'`. I want only `user.email` in the WHERE clause. The expected query should be:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   `accounts` AS `account` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` AS `user` 
        ON `account`.`user_id` = `user`.`id` 
WHERE  `account`.`password` = 'PASSWORD' 
    AND `user`.`email` = 'xyz@gmail.com';
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put the where filter for the users table in the include section:

```js
    models.account.findAll({
      attributes: ['password'],
      include: [{
        model: models.user,
        where: {
          email: email
        }
      }],
      where: {
        password: password
      }
    }).then(function(res){
      console.log(res);
    });
```